# RMarkdown ioslides - Slide number does not show in browser

Tags: r, google-chrome, r-markdown

I'm making a slideshow in RStudio using RMarkdown and exporting to ioslides. This works fine in the RStudio preview window, but when i open the html file in my browser (Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 m (64-bit)), the slide number (n/total) is not displayed, only the "/". (Also, code highlights shown as just bold).

This happens even if i use the example slides in RStuido.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Edit:
I think it happens with every document, but here is one example, that doesn't show page numbers in the browser:

```
---
title: "test"
author: "JohannesNE"
date: "28. sep. 2015"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
```

Comment: Can you make an simple example that gives the error?

Comment: I added one, but i think it will reproduce the problem for most other people.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue in Chrome, but it seems to work fine in Firefox.

Comment: From what I can tell through examining the source code within Chrome, this may be related to certain lines of JS not firing and is most likely browser specific.

Comment: @aashanand it seems like in chrome there is nothing in ::after where there should be a function to input the numbers. Maybe this could be manually fixed with custom css?

Comment: Bad answer: You can get rid of the slide numbers by placing this style into the .Rmd
<style type="text/css">
slides > slide:not(.nobackground):after {
  slide_numbers: true;
}
</style>

Comment: Alternative: you could file an issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues) with a minimal reprex.

Comment: @aashanand, I can see, that that was done just five days ago. https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/517

Comment: It's a security error in Chrome. One workaround is to build the slides, then do either `Rscript -e 'servr::httd()' -p9999` or `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9999` in the directory of the slide HTML file then browse to `http://localhost:9999/test.html`. That should show the #'s and avoid the security error issue.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I think that's a very reasonable answer for a bounty claim

Comment: And it's been fixed as of today in the `rmarkdown` github: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/718e101d8bc095e50d25170ae0a9804c2dd1b18e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a security error in Chrome.

One workaround is to build the slides, then do either:

```
Rscript -e 'servr::httd()' -p9999
```

or

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9999
```

in the directory of the slide HTML file then browse to http://localhost:9999/test.html.

That should show the #'s and avoid the security error issue until the RStudio folks can find a way to adapt the HTML to meet Chrome's security requirements.

**NOTE** that this was fixed on October 1, 2015 - https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/718e101d8bc095e50d25170ae0a9804c2dd1b18e (thus this workaround is no longer needed if you use what is now the github version but will soon be the CRAN version of `rmarkdown`).